# Modified Bessel function of the second kind as an integral

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

While trying to solve a problem on my own (Maxwell-Juttner distribution). I found the following integral:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} p^2 e^{-βmc^2 \sqrt{1 + (\frac{p}{mc})^2}} dp$$

I know the answer is supposed to be in terms of the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_2 (βmc^2)$.

My guess was that the obvious way to go was using the formula I found in Wikipedia:

$$K_α (x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh(t)} \cosh(αt) dt$$

Which gives:

$$K_2 (βmc^2) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-βmc^2 \cosh(t)} \cosh(2t) dt$$

My idea was first to use the variable substitution $\frac{p}{mc} = u$ such that

$$I = (mc)^3 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-βmc^2 \sqrt{1 + u^2}} u^2 du$$

The integrals look very similar, but I still haven't been able to write $I$ in terms of $K_2 (βmc^2)$. My attempt was to make the substitution $u = \sinh(t)$ because $\sqrt{1 + u^2} = \sqrt{1 + \sinh ^2 (t)} = \cosh(t)$.  so:

$$\frac{I}{(mc)^3} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-βmc^2 \sqrt{1 + u^2}} u^2 du = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-βmc^2 \cosh(t)} \sinh ^2 (t) d(\sinh(t)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-βmc^2 \cosh(t)} \sinh ^2 (t) \cosh(t) dt$$

This however is not quite the same as the $K_2 (βmc^2)$ integral and so far I've found no way of actually expressing $I$ purely in terms of $K_2 (βmc^2)$ at all. What would be a good approach? I believe I am very close to the solution.

Comment: I would use integration by parts on this, integrating the exponential term and treating what is left as sinh(2t) which will differentiate to what you want. Use some reasoning with the boundary term on evaluation at infinity should be zero.

Comment: Another way: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x\sqrt{1+u^2}}u^2\,du=\int_1^\infty e^{-xv}v\sqrt{v^2-1}\,dv=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{K_1(x)}{x}=\frac{K_2(x)}{x}.$$